# how to use form in React as a component

Tags: reactjs

I tried to put a form in a separate reusable component but when used that way I can't type anything into the input. I observed, that after entering one letter (it does not appear in the input box) it seems that React rerender the whole component and the name is updated with the inserted letter.

in the version 2 the same code works correctly.

```
// the part same for the both versions 
const [userdata, setUser] = useState({});
  const { name } = userdata

const handleChange = key => event => {
    setUser({
      ...userdata,
      [ key ]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  const submitEdit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleChange();
  };
```

```
// VERSION 1. doesn't work

const FormEdit = () => (
    <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input onChange={handleChange("name")} type="text"/>
          </div>
          <button onClick={submitEdit}> Submit </button>
    </form>
)
return (
     <Layout>
         <div>
           {name} //<-it shows only one letter
           <FormEdit />
         </div>
     </Layout>
);
```

```
// VERSION 2 -> works properly
return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        {name} //<-the updated name is shown immediately
        <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input onChange={handleChange("name")} type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={submitEdit}> Submit </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default User;
```

Comment: Can you please format your code so that each attempt is more distinct? Maybe by putting them in separate blocks? Also is the state hook inside a component that you left out?

Comment: You also shouldn't declare components within a component. There's no benefit, only drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is directly related to declaring the `FormEdit` component within the other component. Here's why:

In a functional component, everything declared inside gets destroyed and re-created each render. It's no different than a normal function call. This is what makes React's hooks so special. They keep track of values in between renders and make sure they are re-created with the correct values.

You're declaring the `FormEdit` component inside a function, which means not only is it re-declared every render, but as a side-effect it also *un-mounts* and remounts each render as well.

This has a few different effects:

1. The component's input loses focus every render.
2. It's impossible for it to maintain its own state.
3. It's not very performant.

Below is a working example to demonstrate.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  // the part same for the both versions 
  const [userdata, setUser] = useState({});
  const { name } = userdata

  const handleChange = (key) => (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...userdata,
      [ key ]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  const submitEdit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleChange();
  };

  const FormEdit = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('mount');
      return () => console.log('unmount');
    }, []);
    
    return (
      <form>
          <div>
            <input onChange={handleChange("name")} type="text"/>
          </div>
          <button onClick={submitEdit}> Submit </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
  
  return (
     <div>
       {name}
       <FormEdit />
     </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As for why you only see the first character; You are not giving the `input` a value, only an `onChange`. If the component does not unmount, this just makes it an "uncontrolled" component. The input still gets it's value updated, you just can't programatically control it. **But**, since it is unmounting and re-mounting every render, it loses its last value every time the user types.

Making it a controlled input would fix this:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  // the part same for the both versions 
  const [userdata, setUser] = useState({});
  const { name } = userdata

  const handleChange = (key) => (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...userdata,
      [ key ]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  const submitEdit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleChange();
  };

  const FormEdit = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('mount');
      return () => console.log('unmount');
    }, []);
    
    return (
      <form>
          <div>
            <input value={name} onChange={handleChange("name")} type="text"/>
            //     ^ Add this
          </div>
          <button onClick={submitEdit}> Submit </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
  
  return (
     <div>
       {name}
       <FormEdit />
     </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This is a little better, but still not ideal. Now it keeps the value each update, but it still loses focus. Not a very good user experience.

This final solution is to **never declare a component within another component**.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const FormEdit = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mount');
    return () => console.log('unmount');
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <form>
        <div>
          <input value={props.name} onChange={props.handleChange("name")} type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={props.submitEdit}> Submit </button>
    </form>
  )
}

const Example = () => {
  // the part same for the both versions 
  const [userdata, setUser] = useState({});
  const { name } = userdata

  const handleChange = (key) => (event) => {
    setUser({
      ...userdata,
      [ key ]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  const submitEdit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleChange();
  };
  
  return (
     <div>
       {name}
       <FormEdit name={name} handleChange={handleChange} submitEdit={submitEdit} />
     </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now it only mounts once, keeps focus, and updates as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass your form handlers to the child component as props so that the lifted state can be manipulated from the child.

```
// Parent Component
...
const [userdata, setUser] = useState({});
const { name } = userdata

const handleChange = key => event => {
    ...
};

const submitEdit = event => {
    ...
};

return (
    <Layout>
        <div>
            {name}
            <FormEdit handleChange={handleChange} submitEdit={submitEdit}/>
        </div>
    </Layout>
);
```

and then in the child:

```
// Child Component
const FormEdit = (props) => (
    <form>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input onChange={props.handleChange("name")} type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={props.submitEdit}> Submit </button>
    </form>
)
```

Comment: This will cause the App component to re-render every time the input is changed and hence you'll be able to enter a single character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FormEdit` component which is inside the `App` component is causing the entire `App` component to re-render when the state gets updated onChange and hence you can only enter only one character at a time. It is generally not a great idea to declare a component within a component. Refer [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html) link for more info. All you have to do is pull the `FormEdit` component out of the `App` component in its own separate function and pass the change handlers as props to the `FormEdit` component. Have a look at the working code below.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const FormEdit = ({ handleChange, submitEdit, name }) => {
  return (
    <form>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input onChange={handleChange('name')} type='text' value={name || ''} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={submitEdit} type='submit'>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [userdata, setUser] = useState();
  const { name } = userdata || {};

  const handleChange = key => event => {
    setUser(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, [key]: event.target.value };
    });
    event.persist();
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const submitEdit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleChange();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {name || ''}
        <FormEdit
          handleChange={handleChange}
          submitEdit={submitEdit}
          name={name}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```